# What does the command "chattr +c /some/dir/" do?

Tags: ext4, xattr

I'm trying to keep a bunch of plain text files compressed using the extended attribute option - `c` on a debian ppc64 system. I ran the following commands:

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/test/compressed
# mount /dev/test/compressed /mnt/compressed/
# mkdir /mnt/compressed/some/txts/
# chattr +c /mnt/compressed/some/txts/
# df -l

# cp /some/txts/* /mnt/compressed/some/txts/
# sync
# df -l
```

To my surprise, the output of `df -l` tells me the files I copied weren't compressed at all.  I also tried to mount the test file system with the option `user_xattr` and I tried creating it with `mkfs.ext4dev`, but neither worked.  I also checked the output of the commands `lsattr /mnt/compressed/some/txts/`; every line has a `c` in it.

Did I miss something? How come the xattr option `c` doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes sense to have a look at the man page of the programs you use:

> BUGS AND LIMITATIONS
>   The `c', 's',  and`u' attributes are not honored by the ext2 and ext3 filesystems as implemented in the current mainline Linux kernels.

This is not supposed to mean "ext4 works" I guess.

Comment: i did read the man page, and `chattr` comes from e2fsprogs a file system utilities supports Ext2/3/4, it just make me more confused. further more, if kernel did not support `c` option, should `chattr` return an error or something?

Comment: @pingz "Should" != "does" I guess.

Comment: @pingz As you noted yourself "every line has a c in it" `chattr` did it right, didn't fail. So why should it return an error? How is it supposed to know what the kernel will do with this information? On the other hand it would perhaps make sense for the kernel to return an error on trying to set this attribute.